# I need to make a recursive function power (x, n), which returns the result of raise x to the 9th power (xn)

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
def numPotencia(x, n):
    if isinstance(x,int) and isinstance(n,int):
            return aux_xPower(abs(x), abs(n));
    else:
        print("\n""Error: The number needs to be a integer");


def aux_xPower(x,n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1;
    elif n == 1:
        return x;
    else:
        return x * aux_xPower(x-1,n)
```

Comment: You mixed up `x` and `n`.

Comment: So what's the problem exactly?

Comment: n has to be integer and positive (in order to avoid infinite recursion). Are you sure you need x to be an int too?

Comment: elif n == 1: return x; is not useful to speed up your program, since it consists of one more check when n > 1 (it can easily turn in pessimization in the average-case). You can remove it this check, the code will look nicer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. Right now, your code will evaluate expressions like this:

```text
x * (x - 1) * (x - 2) * (x - 3) * ... (does not terminate)
```

What you need to do is change this:

```
return x * aux_xPower(x - 1, n)
```

To this:

```
return x * aux_xPower(x, n - 1)
```

This is necessary because `x^n = x * x^(n - 1)`, `x^n = x * (x - 1)^n`.

Comment: You can mark this answer as correct if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Rewrite** this line and try

```
return x * aux_xPower(x-1,n)
```

**to**

```
return x * aux_xPower(x,n-1)
```

Your base should be same every time.